# EasyAdminBundle ReflectionException at create Backend section of install

Tags: symfony

Having an issue with the final stage of the setup of Easy Admin in a fresh Symfony 3 install,

at the  "Your First Backend" : Creating the backend for those entities just require you to add the following configuration in the app/config/config.yml file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
easy_admin:
    entities:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Product
        - AppBundle\Entity\Category
        - AppBundle\Entity\User
```

When I do this I get error :

> [ReflectionException]                             Class
>   AppBundle\Entity\Product does not exist

All the previous commands for setup installed without error, including installing the assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation of EasyAdminBundle You have

`Let's suppose that your Symfony application defines three Doctrine ORM entities called Product, Category and User.`

In `entities` section you need to list already existing in your app Entities. If you don't have any - create it.

Docs: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/getting-started/2-first-backend.md

Comment: Thanks very much, I had started adding the entities, now am getting an error when trying to add an entity, or even clear the cache:  Call to a member function getMetadataFactory() on null in /project /vendor/javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle/Configuration/MetadataConfigPass.php on line 37

Comment: Looks like Your class defined in `entities` is not proper Entity. Make sure that you have done all required steps in entity creation. Check Symfony/Doctrine docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class 

Your entity must be visible in output of `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=dev`

Comment: You are absolutely correct - I made the mistake of choosing php as the entity type, vs the default annotation.  I've remade the entities as annotations, and :         `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=dev
Found 3 mapped entities:
[OK]   AppBundle\Entity\Category
[OK]   AppBundle\Entity\Product
[OK]   AppBundle\Entity\User`     Thanks for your expertise!